# count All non-palindromic substrings in a length n

Tags: algorithm

I'm facing this problem which need to count all substrings in length n 
with the first 26 letters (like they are not palindromic)
I've manged to discover that the palindrome words is

52 * (26<sup>½n</sup> - 1)/25  for even

And 52 * (26<sup>½(n+1)</sup> - 1)/25 for odd

then we subtract it from the general situation

For example:

1 = 26, 2 = 26<sup>2</sup> - 52(26-1)/25 + 26 = 650 ....

I've solved it with mod (10<sup>9</sup>+7) but it's not like the given test cases  which they are 12348 = 981273898 , 9991 = 594358895

Comment: Oh,I'm sorry I used to mathmatics site style

Comment: The Plindromes are 52 and all the words that can br formed = 676, so 676-53 = 624 but the length 1 considring as not plindrome so 624+26=650

Comment: You're given n the length of string such as  2 , ab,ac,aa.... , you're going to find the number of all substrings that they are not plindrome considring that the substring of length 1 is not plindrome , I found the number of plindromes then substract it from the general number